# Azure DevOps AzureFunctionApp@1 not installing python dependencies

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Using the Azure Devops task with current setup :

```
 task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: Deploy Lab
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'serviceConnection'
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: 'myAwesomeApp'
    package: '.'
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.8'
```

Also, in the root directory (ie `.` in the ado task), I have a requirements.txt file that contains `numpy`

The deployment runs successfully but when I test the app, I have the following error:

> Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Which simply means that the requirements.txt file is not considered or pip install -r requirements.txt didn't run successfully in the remote compute, what am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: Added a step to install the packages locally did work, but as numpy is a C built library it's dependent on the host machine and that doesn't work in the remote function app :lol:

The step that I added is this one:

```
- bash: pip install -r requirements.txt --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages"
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'
```

And the error:

> Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS
> FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE! Importing the numpy
> C-extensions failed. This error can happen for many reasons, often due
> to issues with your setup or how NumPy was installed. We have compiled
> some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html Please
> note and check the following: * The Python version is: Python3.9 from
> "/usr/local/bin/python" * The NumPy version is: "1.22.3" and make sure
> that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully study the
> documentation linked above for further help. Original error was: No
> module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' . Troubleshooting Guide:
> https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",
> line 305, in _handle__function_load_request func =
> loader.load_function( File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py",
> line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py",
> line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py",
> line 85, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in
> import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
> level) File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
> File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 986, in
> _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked File "",
> line 850, in exec_module File "", line
> 228, in _call_with_frames_removed File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/bilans/main.py", line 24, in  from .
> import bilan File "/home/site/wwwroot/bilans/bilan.py", line 16, in
>  import numpy as np File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py",
> line 144, in  from . import core File
> "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py",
> line 49, in  raise ImportError(msg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you will have to use python 3.9 and the latest ubuntu agent in the pipeline

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/904